# Missing TestContext.WriteLine Win8 Library Unit Test

Tags: windows-8, mstest

I am creating Unit Tests for a Win8 Library and noticing that the TestContext.Writeline method is not an Intellisense option.   Is there a Win8 specific reason for this?  Could be a Visual Studio bug?  Thanks for participating in this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for a method that's part of a different unit test framework. For a regular .NET application, you'd be using [this TestContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`) which does include `WriteLine`.

For a Windows Store app, the Unit Test project brings in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework`. There's [some documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/ff770525.aspx), but I'm not finding a MSDN reference page for the namespace/class.

FWIW, the lack of `WriteLine` on this class was [reported via Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750514/vs-2012-rc-testcontext-missing-attributes) and closed as By Design.

Comment: seems odd that you cannot use WriteLine on Win8 Store Unit tests.  No indication on the Connect article on why it was omitted and if there is a work around.